# Identify credit/debit card country of origin with Braintree?

Tags: credit-card, braintree

I'm aware that the first 6 digits of card numbers represent the Issuer Identification Network (IIN) of the card and this information should in turn identify the country of origin.

Does Braintree offer any API to decode this information prior to processing a transaction? I'm not aware of any service at present that does so. I'd like to know where a card originates from before completing a transaction as this may have material implications for transaction fees, commissions etc. in my particular use case.

In a similar vein, I'd like to be able to differentiate debit vs. credit cards, though it seems this is not strictly possible simply by considering the IIN.

Comment: It would be helpful to know why this question was down-voted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, you can always [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

If you store a credit card with Braintree, the response will [include BIN Database information](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+python/reference/response/credit-card):

> - country_of_issuance - The country that issued the credit card.
> - debit - Whether the card is a debit card. Possible values:
>
>   ```
>   Braintree::CreditCard::Debit::Yes
>   Braintree::CreditCard::Debit::No
>   Braintree::CreditCard::Debit::Unknown
>   ```

Answer (score 1):

Both issuing country and debit/credit card flag are technically available if you have access to the IIN database published by the American Bankers Association. However access to this database (which is updated monthly) is generally reserved for those participating as a Payment Service Provider or higher.

If you don't have access to that you may be worth having a look at https://www.bindb.com/api-documentation.html (Though fair warning - I haven't used it personally)